# Using a LESS variable as a property instead of a value

Tags: less, mixins

I've made the following two Mixins:

```
.responsive_color(@color, @response_color, @speed: 0.1s){
     color:                  @color;
    .transition(color, @speed);

    &:hover, &:active, &:focus{
        color:                  @response_color;
    }
}

.responsive_background(@color, @response_color, @speed: 0.1s){
    background-color:       @color;
    .transition(background-color, @speed);

    &:hover, &:active, &:focus{
        background-color:       @response_color;
    }
}
```

Since these two are nearly identical I want to combine them into something like this:

```
.responsive(@property, @color, @response_color, @speed: 0.1s){
    @property:              @color;
    .transition(@property, @speed);

    &:hover, &:active, &:focus{
        @property:                  @response_color;
    }
}
```

While this doesn't cause errors in the LESS parser (PHP class) it is simply ignored.
I've also tried @{property} and '@{property}' but both of these cause errors.

Does anyone know how I can output @property to be properly parsed?
Or am I trying to do something that isn't possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A similar question has been answered here that may help you. That particular feature isn't in the LESS.js framework (yet), but you can possibly get around it with a little hack, outlined here:

[How to pass a property name as an argument to a mixin in less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689152/how-to-pass-a-property-name-as-an-argument-to-a-mixin-in-less)

Comment: To bad that it has to be a hack, but it's good to know that it's on the agenda. Until that time I can live with the hack.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Just a quick update. Now the feature is there:

> Properties can be interpolated, e.g. @{prefix}-property: value; 
>   — [Less.js 1.6.0 changelog](https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#160)

So if you're using Less 1.6 or later, now you can actually do it like this:

```
@{property}: @response_color;
```

More info in [this great SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15443008/2816199).