# Is there a generic way to add vendor prefixes in LESS?

Tags: less

I currently have a `mixins.less` file, where almost all mixins are basically the same:

```
.border-radius(@radius) {
  -webkit-border-radius: @radius;
   -khtml-border-radius: @radius;
     -moz-border-radius: @radius;
          border-radius: @radius;
}

.box-shadow(@value) {
  -webkit-box-shadow: @value;
   -khtml-box-shadow: @value;
     -moz-box-shadow: @value;
          box-shadow: @value;
}
```

Is there a way to create some kind of generic mixin, that I could call like this:

```
.vendor('border-radius', '3px');
.vendor('box-shadox', '10px 10px');
```

and which would produce the same result as above?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using an argument for tag name in LESS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14868042/using-an-argument-for-tag-name-in-less)

Comment: @Martin Indeed, sorry for the dup...

Answer (score 40, accepted):

## Notice:

The recommendation is to stop rely on this technique and consider using a dedicated prefixing tool (e.g. [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer), [-prefix-free](https://github.com/LeaVerou/prefixfree) etc.). Hardcoding vendor prefixes via CSS pre-processor mixins (Less, SCSS or whatever) is a pure anti-pattern these days and considered harmful. Auto-prefixing tools will make your code clean, readable, future-proof and easily maintainable/customizable.

See for example: [`less-plugin-autoprefix`](https://github.com/less/less-plugin-autoprefix)

---

#### Original answer:

Well, currently LESS does not support "property name interpolation" so you cannot use a variable in property names. There's a hack however: [How to pass a property name as an argument to a mixin in less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689152/how-to-pass-a-property-name-as-an-argument-to-a-mixin-in-less)
So if you don't mind "dummy" properties in the output CSS, here we go:

```css
.property_(@property, @value) {
    _: ~"; @{property}:" @value;
}

.vendor(@property, @value) {
    .property_('-webkit-@{property}', @value);
    .property_( '-khtml-@{property}', @value);
    .property_(   '-moz-@{property}', @value);
    .property_(          @property,   @value);
}

#usage {
    .vendor(border-radius, 3px);
    .vendor(box-shadow, 10px 10px);
}
```

Output:

```css
#usage {
  _: ; -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  _: ; -khtml-border-radius: 3px;
  _: ; -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  _: ; border-radius: 3px;
  _: ; -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px;
  _: ; -khtml-box-shadow: 10px 10px;
  _: ; -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px;
  _: ; box-shadow: 10px 10px;
}
```

---

#### Update:

Less v1.6.0 introduced [Property Interpolation](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-properties) feature so now you don't need any hacks anymore:

```css
.vendor(@property, @value) {
    -webkit-@{property}: @value;
     -khtml-@{property}: @value;
       -moz-@{property}: @value;
            @{property}: @value;
}

#usage {
    .vendor(border-radius, 3px);
    .vendor(box-shadow, 10px 10px);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the update, it's good to know it's now possible anyway!

Comment: The line `@property : @value;` assigns @value to @property, and thus breaks... Should be `@{property} : @value;`

Comment: @Andreas Hultgren, Yes, sure, my bad - fixed now.

Comment: @seven-phases-max how is hardcoding vendor via less an anti-pattern?

Comment: @Andrew Because you can write normal code w/o prefixes and cluttered mixins and get everything prefixed automatically via specialized tools. Though it's all already written in the notice.