# LESS string interpolation with Crunch?

Tags: css, escaping, less, string-interpolation

Reading some articles about string interpolation in LESS I've tried the following, which didn't work for me:

```
.wk (@property, @data) {
                 @property: @data;
    ~"-webkit-@{property}": @data;
}
```

If i try to compile this, using Crunch, I get an error:

> Unrecognized Input

Is there another way to escape this or get this compiled?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately less doesn't support property name interpolation, but [this answer has a great hack for doing it anyway.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18558614/1388017) But it results in a bunch of dummy, useless  rules. So you end up with something like this:

```
#usage {
  _: 0 ; -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  _: 0 ; -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  _: 0 ; border-radius: 3px;
}
```